# Saying that two letters have the same quantifier without specifying a number in Regex

Tags: regex

**Example**

```
string1 = aaaaabbbbb
regex1 = a{5}b{5}

string2 = aabb
regex2 = a{2}b{2}

string2 = aaabbb
regex2 = a{3}b{3}
```

You will see that the 3 examples above I need to specify quantifiers of them.

Instead of saying

> We have 5 `a` following by 5 `b`.
>
> We have 2 `a` following by 2 `b`.
>
> We have 3 `a` following by 3 `b`.

I want to say

> We have `a` following by `b` where `a` and `b` have the same quantifier.

It is possible or not that I will use only one regex to catch all these patterns, the Regex might similar to this

```
a{n}b{n}
```

where `n` stands for any number.

Note that the best answer should also be able to solve `aaaxyzbbb`, `aaaaxyzbbbb`, ...

Comment: @terces907 That's not enormously clear from your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this too without recursion:

```
(?:a(?=[^b]*(\1?+b)))+\1
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP3qC9/1)

or with a conditional test:

```
(?:a(?=[^b]*((?(1)\1b|b))))+\1
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP3qC9/2)

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved with **recursion**. For example:

```
 a(?R)?b
```

However, the exact syntax and whether it is supported in the first place depends on the regex flavor you are using.

See [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) for more information.

Comment: Be careful, regular-expressions.info has changed these urls.

Comment: How about in case aaaxyzbbb, aaaaxyzbbbb, which solution can solve this?

Comment: @terces907 [like this](https://regex101.com/r/lR5qB2/1): `a(?:xyz|(?R))b` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to evenly match the same number of `a` & `b`, you can use recursion with in your regular expression,

Eg: `/a(?R)?b/`

Above pattern will match:

- ab
- aabb
- aaabbb
- aaaabbbb

Please note that not all the regex engines support **recursion**, but if you are using a PCRE based engined you will be able.