# How to match the recursive pattern `a(?R)b` including another string e.g. "test{aaabbb}"? (Regex)

Tags: regex, recursion, pcre

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336878/saying-that-two-letters-have-the-same-quantifier-without-specifying-a-number-in/32337151#32337151), how to use recursive pattern if my string is not simple like

```
aaaaabbbbb
aabb
aaabbb
```

but they including another text e.g.

```
test{aaaaabbbbb}
test{aabb}
test{aaabbb}
```

where here I want to match a recursive pattern including `test{...}`.

For sure regex:`test\{a(?R)*b\}` should not work.

Note that I prefer regex in PCRE form

Comment: Which language/library/tool are you using? ("Regex" is a cover name for a variety of similar notations. Different languages/libraries/tools differ in the exact feature-sets they support. So you have to tag your question appropriately.)

Comment: The question is based on [Saying that two letters have the same quantifier without specifying a number in Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336878/saying-that-two-letters-have-the-same-quantifier-without-specifying-a-number-in/32337151#32337151) where the accepted answer (linked to in the question) are for PCRE.

Comment: @ruakh I added the last line for you. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the [*recursive* regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) with [*subroutine call*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html):

```
test\{(a(?1)*b)\}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF5zR3/1)

> These are very similar to regular expression recursion. Instead of matching the entire regular expression again, a subroutine call only matches the regular expression inside a capturing group. You can make a subroutine call to any capturing group from anywhere in the regex. If you place a call inside the group that it calls, you'll have a recursive capturing group.

Also, please check the [*Matching Balanced Constructs*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html#balanced) section.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you will need to use a **named subroutine call** to avoid the recusion to affect the entire expression,

Eg. `test\{(?<x>a(?&x)?b)\}`